# hvplot with more than one y-value does not plot

Tags: python, plot, hvplot

I want to "area-plot" a simple dataframe with hvplot (like here: https://hvplot.pyviz.org/user_guide/Plotting.html ), but the code does not work. Since I am new to hvplot I dont quite get the Error Message

Ploting the dataframe as a "bar-Plot"

```py
df.hvplot.bar(x='col2', y=['col1', 'col3'])
```

kinda works. But the legend is not on point. The same as an area plot does not work.

```py
import pandas as pd
import panel as pn
import hvplot.pandas
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

d = {'col1': [1, 2,3,4,5], 'col2': ['a','b', 'c', 'd', 'e'], 'col3': [11,12,13,14,15]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

df.hvplot.area(x='col2', y=['col1', 'col3'])
```

Running my Code gives the following Error Message:

```py
AttributeError: unexpected attribute 'plot' to Legend, possible attributes are background_fill_alpha, background_fill_color, border_line_alpha, border_line_cap, border_line_color, border_line_dash, border_line_dash_offset, border_line_join, border_line_width, click_policy, glyph_height, glyph_width, inactive_fill_alpha, inactive_fill_color, items, js_event_callbacks, js_property_callbacks, label_height, label_standoff, label_text_align, label_text_alpha, label_text_baseline, label_text_color, label_text_font, label_text_font_size, label_text_font_style, label_text_line_height, label_width, level, location, margin, name, orientation, padding, spacing, subscribed_events, tags, title, title_standoff, title_text_align, title_text_alpha, title_text_baseline, title_text_color, title_text_font, title_text_font_size, title_text_font_style, title_text_line_height or visible

:NdOverlay   [Variable]
   :Area   [col2]   (value,Baseline)
```

Comment: Which version of hvplot are you using? I have hvplot 0.5.2 and holoviews 1.12.5 and your code works fine with me. Maybe you have to upgrade your current version of hvplot and holoviews.

Comment: I have got hvplot 0.5.2 and holoview 1.12.6

Comment: After upgradeing from bokeh 1.3.4 to 1.4.0 everything worked fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is correct. 
In conclusion, it thus depended on the library versions you were using. 
It works when you upgrade to bokeh 1.4.0, hvplot 0.5.2 and holoviews 1.12.6.